# How to resize a partittion on Linux for install Windows Seven?

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning

When I installed Redhat Enterprise Linux 5.4 on my laptop,  there is only one partition(about 490G) and a swap partition, now I want to create another partition to install windows 7.

What should I do? 
Which tools can be used to manage partitions on RedHat linux ?

Answer (score 0):

you could see if redhat liniux comes with gparted, or use a package manager to get gparted

Answer (score 0):

Gparted comes with a bootable CD version, as you can not resize a partition you are using, this is the best solution. Search for gparted, download the bootable CD image, burn a CD and restart your machine using this CD.
Gparted will then allow you to resize your partition to leave room for windows.

I don't know how windows 7 support other system, but (very) old windows installs used to start by re-formatting any disk with another system on it...
So it used to be recommended to first install windows, then install any Linux distrib.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I downloaded gparted, but the partition was lvm2 formated. Can gparted handle lvm2 ?

Comment: Aaargh, it can not resize it. From the features table, it can read but it can not resize lvm2 volumes.
In this case you need to resize the filesystem first, using the filesystem specific tool, then you need to resize the logical volume with lvresize or lvreduce (lvm2 specific).
Once done, you can resize the partition with gparted.

Comment: I forgot the most important: before doing anything, do a backup of all the important files.